# Unable to Add Child in Title Bar of applicationLayout of Extension Library

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I want to include pop up menu in Title bar (application layout) and want to add multiple child against page link node. I have added child but system is not showing required control at run time. One main link is appearing. Can you please guide me how can I make required drop down menu in Title bar?

It's working perfectly in Place Bar but some not working in title bar.

Thanks,
Qaiser Abbas

Comment: Please show your code you have so far.

Comment: Thanks @KnutHerrmann for prompt response. I have using applicationLayout control of extension library. There is no code it just configurations in title bar

Comment: I meant as code the relevant part of XPage's source code.

Comment: There is no code it's just configurations of layout control. I insert Page link node in title bar, child node under the main node. It's not working but same case is working in place bar. <xe:pageTreeNode label="My Department">
      <xe:this.children>
       <xe:pageTreeNode label="Initiated"
        enabled="true" page="/My_Department_Page.xsp">
       </xe:pageTreeNode>
      </xe:this.children>
     </xe:pageTreeNode>

Comment: May be you should have a look at the Extended OneUI Application Layout on OpenNTF, which gives you much more flexibility through editable areas. https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-8RWCAM